# Very basic Javascript constructors problem

Tags: javascript, constructor

In the following JavaScript code main() is called.
My question is why the second constructor is called rather than the first one ?
What am I missing here ?

Thanks !!

```
function AllInputs() {
   alert("cons 1");
   this.radioInputs = [];
   alert(this);
}

function AllInputs(radioElement) {
   alert("cons 2");
   this.radioInputs = [radioElement];
   alert(this);
}

AllInputs.prototype.toString = function() {
   return "[object AllInputs: radioInputs: " + this.radioInputs.length + "]";
}

function main() {
   var result = new AllInputs();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript does not support overloaded functions.

When you define the same function twice, the second definition replaces the first one.

Instead, you should make a single function, and check `arguments.length` to see how many arguments were passed.

For example:

```
function AllInputs(radioElement) {
   this.radioInputs = arguments.length ? [radioElement] : [];
   alert(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the last definition of an identifier is used:

```
function foo() { return "bar"; }
var foo = "foo";

alert(foo);
```

In that case, `foo` was a variable with the value "foo".  Had `foo` been a function, it would have simply said that `foo` was a function.  If you don't believe it, try using `alert(foo())` instead of just `alert(foo)`.  You'll most likely get an error in your console log with no visible output like you had with `alert(foo)` (the variable...not the function call).

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo() { ... }
```

is really just shorthand for

```
var foo = function () { ... }
```

Hence, the second time you're declaring the function, you're overwriting the variable `AllInputs` with a different function. There ain't no such thing as two functions with the same name in Javascript, since all functions are really variables.

Comment: Actually, they're not quite the same.

Comment: @SLaks Then maybe "they handle like variables"?